# PySide QInputDialog.getInt() return value?

Tags: python, qt, pyside

The documentation says the function returns an integer :
https://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QInputDialog.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QInputDialog.getInt

But when I run the following code :

```
year = QInputDialog.getInt(self, QApplication.applicationName(),
    "Enter the year.", QDate().currentDate().year()-1)
print("year = ", year)
```

... I get a 2-element tuple :

```
('year = ', (2013, True))
```

That's fair enough, but still, there is a difference. I am missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [static members of QInputDialog](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qinputdialog.html#static-public-members) all set the `ok` parameter (which is a pointer) to `true` if the user pressed OK, or `false` if they pressed Cancel.

So in C++, you'd need to do something like this:

```cpp
 bool ok;
 int year = QInputDialog::getInt(
                 this, QApplication::applicationName(),
                 tr("Enter the year"), QDate::currentDate().year() - 1,
                 minimum, maximum, 1, &ok);
 if (ok)
     ...
```

Since it would be horribly unpythonic to modify arguments in this way, both PyQt and PySide choose instead to return all the values together in a tuple.

And in general, wherever the Qt docs indicate that multiple values may be returned by modifying arguments, you can usually assume PyQt and PySide will return a tuple instead.

Comment: @dplamp. Yes, I very rarely look at the PyQt/PySide docs. The Qt docs are vastly superior - even if you don't know C++.